# Is it possible to use multiple link styles in css?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible like lets say the text in the div header has a red hover, and the text in the div in the footer a white hover?
Or is this just not possible and can you only set 1 style for the whole document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very much possible, just like any other element you can style them separately by being more specific.

If you have this HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <a href="#">First link</a>
</div>

<div id="bot">
    <a href="#">Second link</a>
</div>
```

With this CSS you would style *both* links:

```
a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

With this CSS you can style them separately:

```
#top a:hover {
    color: #f00;
}

#bot a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh oke great! And uhm with link, active, visited works just the same right? I just use a line like this: #top a, link, visited, active?

Gettin wiser everyday :D Thank you and everyone else here helping me :D

Comment: @AlexanderVaz Works the same, yes. But you should take notice that `#top .one, .two` targets `.one` inside of `#top` and **any** `.two`; you would want `#top .one, #top .two`.

Comment: Yea Alexander, also if you just type `a` you will style `link`, `visited`, `hover` and `active` at the same time. Then you can individually style the others to what has to be changed.

Comment: Great! This really helped me alot, I was always fighting witth css to get this done :P

Now 1 more problem, crappy IE messes up my template.. In chrome and firefox works 100%..

Answer (score 6):

You can set as pretty much as many as you want to if you just hook it right:

```
/* every a:hover has color red */
    a:hover { color: red; } 
/* #footer a:hover has color green. */   
    #footer a:hover { color: green; } 
/* Every link that has class ".ThisClass" will have yellow color */
    a.ThisClass:hover { color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

```
#header a:hover {
    color: #f00;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wrygB/2/

You may want to split this though so you can use the same hovers elsewhere.  In which case you would do:

```
.main:hover {
    color: #f00;
}

.sub:hover {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

And then you can apply a class of main or sub to any element to get the hover effect.

Comment: This will not work, `a` elements don't inherit color from their parent so they need to be targeted specifically.

Comment: I provided a working example.  If you view that then you will see that it does indeed work.

Comment: @Gazler Your example does not use a tags. Put a tags in there and you will see what Kokos is talking about.

Comment: @Kokos: I did not see a reference to a elements anywhere, but after re-reading I see it was in the title of the question and not the body.  I have fixed my sample.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'd just select the element the a:link is within, and apply styles like that.

i.e

```
#header a:hover { color: red; }
#footer a:hover { color: white; }
```